Is there a method to transfer iPhone Voice Memos to the cloud or a Windows PC en masse while keeping the original metadata (date created, et cetera)?
This is rather a last resort—I have previously submitted a version of this to Quora (here) and the official Apple Support Community (here) on April 8; the Reddit communities r/iphonehelp (here), r/techsupport (here), and r/applehelp (here) on March 18/19; r/DataHoarder (here) on March 15; and in an earlier stage r/iphonehelp (here) and r/applehelp (here) again on February 23 and 29, respectively. (Why it's been so long for me continue pursuing this is another story.) I highly recommend people read at least the Quora and Apple Support Community post for more context.
Simply put, I want to migrate the Voice Memos currently clogging my iPhone 8 Plus to somewhere else, including context like the exact time they were recorded. If the Windows tools I have could directly access the file system of an iPhone, this would be a non-issue—I would just use DMDE, FreeCommander, or robocopy to copy them to an external drive while retaining metadata, else use DMDE or Clonezilla to just image the whole thing. But unfortunately, since Apple "Thinks Different", this is not an option. While I know you can back up your iPhone files to a Windows PC using iTunes, I don't know for sure whether that retains their (Date created/Date modified) metadata.
So, is there any option for me?

Do Voice Memos no longer sync back to your Library, as they used to?  They used to appear in iTunes like any other media, but I no longer use the first-party app, so I don't know if they appear in Music.

How about a respectable third party app like https://imazing.com/transfer-iphone-notes-voice-memos
It is well regarded and does a whole lot more. You should be able to get a sample of the files before you need to pay for a license.

A few questions about this:

First, are iMazing backups interchangeable with iTunes backups? Second... is there any method to resolve this batshit error (https://sta.sh/0ohiijtvuh7) that wouldn't involve deleting the data that I want preserved (as in, why I asked this question)? I already offloaded almost all apps on it... how much space is required?
